# response.map is not a function

Tags: arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop a request to extract the ID's from a previous request. I followed the steps in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wuvgX-egdc but i can't get it to work. As I see it the problem is that {} is not an array but I would like to search within "campaigns" which seems to be an array. (As you probably understand I'm new to this)

Here's the request I've sent and would like to loop through to extract the ID's that I wish to use in the next request. (there are several hundreds of ID's)

```
{
    "campaigns": [
        {
            "id": 373894,
            "name": "Benriach",
            "created_at": "2022-01-21 13:37:34",
            "sent_at": "2022-01-21 13:37:53",
            "status": "sent",
            "type": "text_message"
        },
```

Here's the test that I'm trying to run.

```
const response = pm.response.json();
const campaignids = response.map (campaignid => campaigns.id);
console.log(campaignids);
pm.variables.set('campaignids', campaignids);
```

Here's how it looks>>
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txqqg.jpg)

The end goal is to use Postman to extract campaign statistics from an e-mail marketing tool and then send it on into Google Data Studio where I want to create a dashboard for e-mail-campaigns using both data from the e-mail marketing tool as well as website data.

Comment: Don't paste url link but paste your code here so that someone can help you

Comment: [why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thanks Manjeet, I've updated the post now. Hope it makes more sense. Please forgive a beginner from the marketing department. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> const campaignids = response.map (campaignid => campaigns.id); here is the problem
> space between `map (`

```
const response = pm.response.json();
const campaignids = response.map(campaign => campaign.id);
console.log(campaignids);
pm.variables.set('campaignids', campaignids);
```

and make sure `response` should be an array

Comment: Thank you so much Manjeet! It worked just fine and now a can extract a list of all campaign-ID's. Do you also know how to make new requestst using these ID's?

Thank you so much Manjeet! It worked just fine and now I can extract a list of all campaign-ID's. Do you also know how to make new automated requestst based on these ID's? 

Every campaign-ID is attached to a statistics report and I would like to send multiple

The most basic way of doing this is to send a request like this https://app.rule.io/api/v2/campaigns/370373/statistics where the ID 370373

Comment: I've tried this in Pre-request Script. 
const campaignids = pm.variables.get('campaignids');
pm.variables.set('currentcampaignids',(campaignids.shift());

if (Array).isArray (campaignids) && campaignids.length > 0) {
    postman.setNextRequest('GET statistics');
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}

Looking at the example in the video I referred to earlier it seems I need to have some content in the Body which is not the case here. Body is empty. Is there a way to use these ID's in a new request?

Comment: @PeterFalk  you need to run the collection  [check here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/intro-to-collection-runs/#starting-a-collection-run)